# Record video 3MP/30 FPS for 9 days

Tags: ffmpeg

I am a Software Engineer but my knowledge on cameras and/or codecs is very limited. I know that recording a video 9 days on 3 MP and 30 FPS would generate a huge file (probably 60 TB+). So compressing the video with an encoder is probably what I need here. I am mainly developing on the .NET Platform. I found ffmpeg to be able to encode existing videos but also Live Input from Webcams or industrial cameras. 
However I am asking how I can achieve this type of task and what I have to take care of. Do you have any tips on this?

My aim would be to generate a video over a time of 9 days in total. Maybe the video cannot be in one file, but I think it would be good to have one file for each hour or something like this. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"it would be good to have one file for each hour"*. See the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment).

Comment: What is the purpose of the video? If you are capturing for machine analysis, a perceptual codec designed for humans may not work for you.